# Casting (not) required

Tags: java, arrays, generics, methods

I wrote a method which returns an ArrayList with values contained in my queue. The queue ArrayList is filled with Node objects and this class has a parameter **values** of type T that is the data that I need to retrieve. I did a getValue method to do this:

```
public T getValue() {
    return value;
  }
```

(The class is of type < T >).
The method in my queue class is this:

```
public ArrayList getArray() {
    ArrayList < T > onlyValues = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++) {
      T tmp = (T)((queue.get(i)).getValue());
      onlyValues.add(tmp);
    }
    return onlyValues;
  }
```

If I execute it without the casting (T) I get this error: `error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to T`
Why? I know that the method **add** accepts Object of type T, and my method in the class Node return a T element.

Comment: Stack Overflow snippets are only for JavaScript/HTML/CSS questions, they are not for Java. I have edited them out.

Comment: This depends on what `queue.get(i)` returns. If queue.get(i) returns Object (which is what it looks like) then you need the cast. Is that your class or from a library?

Comment: It returns a Node object. Through it I get access to the getValue() method which returns a T object

Comment: I'm going to guess you have raw type issues elsewhere in your code, since you do in this code. If you do, fix those. Then see what the error message says. Please show the declaration of `queue`.

Comment: queue = new ArrayList<Node>();

Comment: Stop using *raw* generic types. Turn on the warning in your IDE, so you never accidentally use *raw* generic types again. You're missing the type argument on the return type.

Comment: I don't know if I will fill the node with Integers, String, Longs ecc... How can I define the type argument?

Comment: @JimBelushi2 that's its initialization, not it's declaration. What is the type of the variable?

Comment: private ArrayList <Node> queue;

Comment: @JimBelushi2 and is Node generic? As in, is the class declared like `class Node<T>`? If so, you need to declare `List<Node<T>> queue`.

Comment: Yes, it is generic and I cannot use a List type but only an ArrayList.

Comment: @JimBelushi2 then `ArrayList<Node<T>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are declaring the `queue` variable as

```
private ArrayList <Node> queue;
```

and `Node` is generic, then you are using raw types. Declare the variable as:

```
private ArrayList <Node<T>> queue;
```

Then you will not need to cast:

```
T tmp = queue.get(i).getValue();
```

You are also missing the type parameter on the method return type;

```
public ArrayList<T> getArray() {
```

Note that it would be easier to use an enhanced for loop:

```
for (Node<T> node : queue) {
  onlyValues.add(node.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a difference between a Type and an Object with a property that has a generic type inside of it.  Your ArrayList needs to have objects added.  To fix this, use this instead:

```
onlyValue.add(new Node<T>(tmp));
```

Comment: The new ArrayList must contain only the list of the elements that I get with the getValue() method, not Node objects.